# Why are similar matrices not equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if $B=C^{−1}AC$ for some  invertible $n\times n$ matrix $C$. I know similar matrices are not equal but I want to know why is the following wrong
\begin{align}
B&=C^{-1}AC\\
 &=C^{-1}CA\\
&=IA\\
&=A
\end{align}
Isn't matrix multiplication associative ? I want to know what is wrong with his logic. What am I missing ?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is NOT commutative!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try to come up with examples of $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB\neq BA$, this is quite easy and will help you to understand why your argument is wrong.

Comment: Associativity: $(AB)C=A(BC)$. Commutativity: $AB=BA.$ Matrix multiplication is associative, but not commutative (except in [special cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices)).

Comment: user820368938: Matrix multiplication of $n\times n$ matrices  is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, matrix multiplication is associative. But, when you wrote  $C^{-1}AC=C^{-1}CA$, you assumed that it is commutative and, in general, that is not true.